# LibreOffice Writer edited document is recognized as virus or spyware

Tags: 14.04, firefox, libreoffice, malware

I got MS word document, person asked me to edit it, to add table of contents, to add page numbers, because she doesn't know how to do in MS Office. So I did with LibreOffice writer. But when I saved (tried several filetypes, including: .doc, .docx, .odt) and send file back to her through facebook firefox and chrome showed error in download list saying

"Blocked: May contain a virus or spyware - "

And actually it says same thing when I download file which I sent and try to open it. And when I did edited this file second time, this time with windows and MS word, everything worked just fine.

So what's the problem here... Do I have virus which is unlikely, not even because I'm on linux, but I know how viruses works and I do not open suspicious files, I'm not going to suspicious websites and this ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed 2 weeks ago.

Something should be wrong with LibreOffice, right.. ?

Can't find any info on the internet about this issue...

And I can replicate this by creating new file with LibreOffice Writer, saved it in .odt with random text with two fonts, Times New Roman and LiberationSeriff, sent it via facebook and can not open it, same error...

**Did some experiments and:** it's Times New Roman font what caused the problem... What should I do? I need this font...

**EDITED:** So I turned off this blockage on firefox and I can download file and open it, haven't tried to open it in MS office yet, so not sure if it will work if something really wrong what libre does with MS fonts...

**UPDATE:** well... everything works in MS Office, nothing bad happened with fonts or document when I opened it. So everything works, but still, browser treats it as virus or spyware. :) I guess LibreOffice guys should know that...

Comment: How did you install times? Try removing the font and then run `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` to install that way. (Only pretty sure on that package name, on my mobile right now.)

Comment: I've installed all fonts with ubuntu-restricted-extras and just reinstalled them, no change, still document is recognized as a virus or spyware...

Comment: zip the file and send it zipped ;)

Comment: That's probably a false-positive. You can't do much about that, but you can circumvent it, by putting the document in a Zip archive, possibly an encrypted one and the password sent along with it.

Answer (score 0):

That's probably a false positive. You can't do much about that, but you can circumvent it, by putting the document in a Zip archive using your favourite archive manager.

Some malware scanners peek into archives too, in which case you need to [encrypted your archive](/q/17641) and send the password along with it.